# Converting C++ into Java, how to define array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, type-conversion

I am using the NetBeans IDE to run and compile Java.

This is a piece of code that I have made with C++.

I want to print out the variable `i` when it's not the same as the value it's compared to. This is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int v[5000];
int main(void) {
    int check_self = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < 5000; ++i) {
        //output any value i that is not the same as v[i]
        if(!(v[i])) std::cout << i << '\n';

        check_self = i + (i%10) + (i/10)%10 + (i/100)%10 + (i/1000)%10;
        v[check_self] = 1;
        enter code here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I declare this in Java should it be like this?

```
int v[] = new int [5000];
```

When I tried to write: `if ( ! v [ i ] )`, it shows an error. Is the way Java handles this different?

Comment: `!v[i]` can be written as `v[i] == 0`, which works equally well in both Java and C++.

Comment: yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039647/what-does-conditional-expressions-can-be-only-boolean-not-integral-mean

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is confusing:

```
//output any value i that is not the same as v[i]
if(!(v[i])) std::cout << i << '\n';
```

The C++ code doesn't appear to match the comment.  Do you know that this is what you want in C++?

Here's how to declare that array in Java:

```
int [] v = new int[5000];
```

This will create an array of 5000 zeros.

I think it should be written this way in Java:

```
//output any value i that is not the same as v[i]
if(i != v[i]) { 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```